# Reading feather object in R is slow

Tags: python, r, feather

I am using the `feather` packages for data exchange between Python (collecting the data) and R (used for analysis), writing and reading the data in Python is extremely fast. However, reading the same feather object in R is VERY slow, on the order of minutes for about a 10MB feather object that has about 80K rows and 24 columns. Each time I am reading the feather object locally so it is not due to network latency.

The only thing that I think it could be is, some of the variables (5 to be exact) are `int64` type in Python which get coerced to `double` types when R has import them. This causes R to give the `coercing int64 to double` warning during the reading of the feather object. Can anyone confirm this or is there another explanation?

**EDIT: Coercing is not the problem,** I re-saved the `int64` columns in Python at `int32` and the reading in R is still just as slow. Need help.

**EDIT 2: Example Code** As requested, here is the code I am running. Just reading the feather object from a sub-folder essentially:

```
library(feather)
test_feather = read_feather("C:/my_folder/subfolder/test.feather")
```

Comment: I've used feather with R to read several gigabytes of unstructured text and its extremely fast. Perhaps you could provide your script, per usual stackoverflow standards, so that we may find your user error. Thanks

Comment: @Justin I am just running the read command, so my code is simply `data <-
 read_feather("c:/my_project/subfolder/my_data.feather")`

Comment: `sessionInfo()` and a **reproducible** example please?

Comment: @BenBolker Added the `sessionInfo()` and I don't know how best to post a repoducible example since I can't simple post my feather object here. As I said, it comes from a Python dataframe that is about 50k rows with 25 variables, with a mix of float64, int32, datetimes, and unicode strings

Comment: Could it be due to the data being first handled / written in a Linux system and then trying to read the feather object in R on a windows machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is due to the creation of the `feather` object in a Linux environment while the reading of the same object in R was happening in a windows system. I don't fully know the details but essentially each OS has a different specification when representing binary data on disk.

I don't remember reading this issue / warning in the documentation (though I suppose it is obvious and implicit), but perhaps a little reminder might save some future people from making the same mistake.